# How To Delete A csv file upon Exit of Python Operation

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to make a Python script that reads from a csv file. Upon exit of the Python script or when the Python program is killed or terminated, I want it to delete the csv file that it was reading. How do I do that? Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import csv

count=1

while (count>0):
    csv=np.genfromtxt("csvdata.csv", delimiter=",", filling_values=np.nan, dtype=int, case_sensitive=True, deletechars='', replace_space=' ')
    ref=np.genfromtxt("refdata.csv", delimiter=",", filling_values=np.nan, dtype=int, case_sensitive=True, deletechars='', replace_space=' ')
    A=np.array(csv)
    B=np.array(ref)
    D = B - A[-1]
    match= B[np.abs(D).sum(axis=1).argmin()]
    print match
    count = count + 1
```

I want to delete 'csvdata.csv' upon exit of the Python program. But the codeit has to be in this Python script so it doesn't have to involve manual deletion of the csv. (It is so, because the csv is created repeatedly by another Python script aside from this one)

All help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

edit:

I tried using os to delete the file but it won't work. I also tried changing the paths specified with the `rm`.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import os

count=1

while (count>0):
    csv=np.genfromtxt("csvdata.csv", delimiter=",", filling_values=np.nan, dtype=int, case_sensitive=True, deletechars='', replace_space=' ')
    ref=np.genfromtxt("refdata.csv", delimiter=",", filling_values=np.nan, dtype=int, case_sensitive=True, deletechars='', replace_space=' ')
    A=np.array(csv)
    B=np.array(ref)
    D = B - A[-1]
    match= B[np.abs(D).sum(axis=1).argmin()]
    print match
    count = count + 1

os.system('rm csvdata.csv')
```

Comment: Doesn't your loop just go forever? Don't you need a `break`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could just use:

`os.remove('csvdata.csv')`

If csv file is located in the same directory of the script, or you need to give the path to file. Search about `os.path.join()` to build system independent directories path.

You shouldn't use `os.system('rm csvdata.csv')` since this probably won't work over windows systems, because it's a Unix command. But if you use the remove function this will deal with any OS.

Certifies that your code really stop.

Comment: With Python 3 there is a library called pathlib that can deal with that too. Check this link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink  This approach won't be calling any command to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `os` module to execute a command outside of python.

```
# if csvdata.csv is in your current directory; do 
import os 
os.system("rm csvdata.csv") # linux/mac, definitely
# os.system("del csvdata.csv") # windows, probably  
# .. else; use full path
```

Or run the python script `script.py` from a bash wrapper script `wrapper.sh`, and delete it in there.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "running script..."
python script.py
echo "deleting file..."
rm csvdata.csv
echo "done!"
```

Comment: Will it delete the csv only when the Python operation terminates?

Comment: The Python standard library has functions for filesystem operations. They'll be faster and more portable than using `os.system()`. Generally speaking, calling external programs shouldn't be the first thing you reach for.

Comment: yes @TylerJoseph. Also, @Chris is totally correct regarding `subprocess.run()` as a more complete `os.system()`, at least in python3 (edit) - use `subprocess.call()` in python2.

Comment: I'm not taking about `subprocess.run()`. That's just another way to call an external program. It's still going to be slow and non-portable. Plus, the interface is super awkward. I'm talking about `os.unlink()`, `pathlib`, etc.

Comment: Can you explain it in a beginner's pov, I don't understand those I'm really sorry I'm new to Python. Also, the os module is not working I tried altering the paths but to no avail.

Comment: Hello can you explain it? Thank you